# Counting decimal "points" and decimal places

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i)))
            if (!(s1.charAt(i) == '.')) 
           {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You must enter a number");
                System.exit(0);
           }
```

This code detects all characters except digits or ".".
If it detects any other character it will tell you "you must enter a number" and then close.

Now my question is:

If I write two decimal points like 2.2.3 it will not detect the error.

My second question:

How can I make my program to detect three decimal places and show a message.

Comment: Well, many ways. Count the dots (or just add a boolean flag to mark you have found one already) would fit your current code.

Comment: Use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for parsing the value.

Comment: either what you can do is, convert this to String, split the string with "." if it is 1 or 2 return true else false and check the split array for Number format Exception

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel - [`Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) can already do this for you:

```
String s1 = <some input number>;
try {
    Double.parseDouble(s1);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You must enter a number");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Does this work with numbers that do not fit double? Does it reject scientific notation? (I don't know, so just verifying.)